# How to wildcard redirect old domain to new domain root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this currently set up in my .htaccess:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

However, I want all URLs from the old domain to be redirected to the root of the new domain, (as opposed to redirecting to the same path on the new domain).

Please can someone rectify the above code?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Excellent thanks! Works perfect. Only thing, how am I able to redirect even something like: olddomain.com/? (yes I want to redirect the question mark to newdomain.com).

Comment: Not so easy because Apache removes `?` when alone